# Spark Scala: compute Pearson correlation of 2 Vectors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a DataFrame where each row has 2 vector columns.
Like

```
ratings1 | ratings2
Vector   | Vector
```

And I'm trying to understand how can I use Statistics.corr method to compute similarity score between those two columns for each row.
As for now, I realised that corr doesn't accept two Vectors as parameters. So, should I create an RDD for each pair of Vectors?